# What's best today lighthttpd or Apache with Tomcat?

Tags: lighttpd, tomcat

lighthttpd was hot some time ago with Tomcat. Is it still the case ? I heard apache 6 and Tomcat 6 is lightning fast ?

Answer (score 2):

I recently deployed an app using nginx. There are some notable potential vulnerabilities but if you take some care in configuration they can be avoided. Nginx can be incredibly fast and handles tremendous load when properly configured. I would recommend deploying multiple staging environments with different configurations and then benchmark them under different load conditions to properly evaluate which one best suits your needs.